# Solution of a system of three trigonometric equations with 3 angles

Tags: trigonometry

Can any one solve the system of equations

\begin{cases} \  \ \sin A&+&2\cos B&+&\tan C&=&0\\
2\sin A&+&5\cos B&+&3\tan C&=&0\\
-\sin A&-&5\cos B&+&5\tan C&=&0\end{cases}

How many possible solutions this system may have?
I personally think there are at best 14.

Comment: Hint: Let $x=\sin A, y=\cos B, z=\tan C$

Answer (score 0):

Since the determinant of the coefficient matrix is non-null, the only solution is the $(0,0,0)$ one.
So $A=k\pi$ , $B=\pi /2 +j\pi$, $C=l
\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Setting
$$
x_1=\sin A,\quad x_2=\cos B,\quad x_3=\tan C,
$$
the system becomes
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}[lcl]
xx_1 +2x_2+x_3 &=&0\\
2x_1 +5x_2+3x_3 &=&0\\
-x_1 -5x_2+5x_3 &=&0
\end{array}
\right..
$$
Since the determinant of the matrix
$$
A=\left(\begin{array}[ccc] 01 & 2 & 1\\ 2 & 5 & 3 \\ -1 & -5 & 5
\end{array}\right) 
$$
is
$$
\det(A)= 1\cdot(5\cdot 5+5\cdot 3)-2\cdot(2\cdot5+1\cdot3)+2\cdot-5+1\cdot 5=9 \ne 0,
$$
the above system has a unique solution, i.e
$$
(x_1, x_2, x_3)=(0.0.0).
$$
Solving each of the equations
$$
\sin A=0,\quad \cos B=0, \quad \tan C=0,
$$
we ger
$$
A=k\pi, \quad  B=\frac{\pi}{2}+l\pi,\quad C=m\pi
$$
where $k,l,m$ are integers.